# indexOf for angular typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, indexof, angular-ng-if

I am trying to write a similar **`true/false`** statement, Similar to how the `.selected()` method would work in `Angular typescript`.

The idea is to show an image if the calculation or `*ngIf` statement evaluates to `True`. The code is written in the `app.html` side

Code:

```
<img src="/project/x.png" *ngIf="selectedimage.indexOf(v) !== -1"><a href="{{i['link']}}" target="blank" (click)="update_viewed(z)">
```

There is a `*ngFor` statement right before this code, with `;let z = index` at the end. The overall code creates a # of rows dynamically depending on how many elements exist in an array. (code not provided for this here.) Then, if the user clicks on the `href` link, the index value is passed into a method, which pushes it to an array. in `console.log(this.selectedimage)` I can see the values being added in each time I click the `href` reference. Not sure why the `ngIf` logic isn't working.

All help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use indexOf with *ngIf on the template, I would recommend you to create a function that returns true/false based on the logic. Use indexOf within the function and call it with *ngIf

Comment: Would I then just “return value” from the function being called in thr ngIf?

Comment: Yeah you can do that too

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. I'm finding typescript to be a little complicated, still learning, but thanks again for taking time to recommend a direction.

Comment: Glad to help you

Comment: Hi@Sajeetharan, I think you are wrong here, You said -" You cannot use indexOf with *ngIf on the template." it's not correct, We can use indexOf() in the template.
check it by placing it in the template, Its works.
<img src="https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/hd-wallpapers-1.jpg" *ngIf="selectedimage.indexOf(v) !== -1">.

Comment: @ShubhamVerma thanks for the headsup, i always prefer to use in the component than on the template

Comment: @Sajeetharan you can recommend using in the component than on the template but you cannot say that "You cannot use indexOf with *ngIf on the template."