# Angular 6 - How to Use indexOf in Interpolated String

Tags: angular

I have an array of `user.elements` as below:

```
user.elements = ['Water', 'Fire', 'Earth', 'Metal'];
```

The syntax that I have in Angular 6:

`<p [ngClass]="{'green-color': user.elements.indexOf('Water') != -1}">Water</p>`

I got following error message as `undefined`:

`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined`

I'd like to know how can we use `indexOf` on interpolated string in Angular 6?

Thanks,

Comment: can you show us all the code how u have declared the user object. It basically is saying that elements is undefined.  there is nothing wrong in the indexOf method.

Comment: There is already a subject about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51296798/indexof-for-angular-typescript

Comment: @Lounis This is not the same question. The code itself in the question isn't incorrect, it's just that the array is undefined. It works when the array isn't undefined: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qkffbu

Comment: @KurtHamilton, exactly it's true, your code works well, perhaps because OP doesn't define user.elements in `ngOnInit()` It seems to be data issue.

Comment: use `user?.elements?.indexOf()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a problem with `indexOf`, you are probably trying to use `user.elements` before it is already set.

Comment: Thanks, it was my mistake. When I check back, user.element is an array of objects instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code instead

```
<p *ngIf="user" [ngClass]="{'green-color': user.elements.indexOf('Water') != -1}">Water</p>
```

Comment: OR you can use "?"
<p [ngClass]="{'green-color': user?.elements.indexOf('Water') != -1}">Water</p>

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that you try to call 'user.elements' before 'user' actually assigned.
Plus, I'd use the includes function which returns a boolean.

```
<p *ngIf="user" [ngClass]="{'green-color': user.elements.includes('Water')}">Water</p>
```

or

```
<p [ngClass]="{'green-color': user?.elements.includes('Water')}">Water</p>
```